# Unknown flag error diffset 'stable'

Tags: matlab, set

I am trying to use diffset, with the set being stable, but i get a `Unknown flag.` error. I also tried it with `sorted`, but the same error applies. Is there a different syntax?

My code:

```
C = setdiff([4 1 3 2],[2 1],'sorted')
```

I am using Matlab 7.10.0 r2010a

Comment: please check your matlab version. these flags were introduced only recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, this is probably a MATLAB version issue. The behavior of `setdiff` has changed in the last versions, and the [online documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) covers only MATLAB's latest 2013a release, so this may be a possible reason for your confusion.

That said, the documentation for previous MATLAB releases is [also available online](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html) (note that it requires a MathWorks account, though). In any case, your MATLAB seems to have the older implementation of the `setdiff` command, and you can verify that by:

```
help setdiff
```

Anyway, the behavior of the older implementation of `setdiff` is similar to the behavior of the newer implementation when the flag *setOrder* is set to `'sorted'`. If you want to mimic the behavior when the flag *setOrder* is set to `'stable'`, you can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) instead, for example:

```
A = [4 1 3 2];
B = [2 1];
C = A(~ismember(A, B))
```

which yields:

```
C =
     4     3
```

Comment: exactly what i needed :), a side question: why introduce stable then? is there a faster implementation?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski I don't think so, it's just shorter syntax. In your example `setdiff` could also save you the temporary variables.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://mrmartin.net/?p=269) offers an implementation:

```
function [res]=setdiff_stable(a,b)
    if(size(a,1)>size(a,2))
        a=a';
    end
    if(size(b,1)>size(b,2))
        b=b';
    end
    res=a(sum(repmat(a,length(b),1)-repmat(b',1,length(a))==0,1)==0);
end
```